# How to change dot to comma in R

Tags: r

```
get_bike_data <- function(url) {
  
  html_bike_category <- read_html(url)
  
  
  
  # Get the names
  bike_name_tbl <- html_bike_category %>%
    html_nodes(css = ".catalog-category-bikes__title-text") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_remove_all(pattern = "\n") %>%
    enframe(name = "position", value = "name")
    

  # Get the prices
  bike_price_tbl <- html_bike_category %>%
    html_nodes(css = ".catalog-category-bikes__price-title") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_remove_all(pattern = "\\.")%>%
    extract_numeric()%>%
    enframe(name = "position", value = "price_euro") %>%
    left_join(bike_name_tbl)
    
}

# 2.3.1b Alternative with a for loop

# Create an empty tibble, that we can populate

# Loop through all urls

bike_data_tbl <- bike_data_tbl %>%
  rename("model" = "name")%>%
  subset(nchar(price_euro)!=0)
  
  
bike_data_tbl
```

[image]

this is a data of price and model from a website. I wanted to change the 1.699 to 1,699. Although I tried many other methods(format(decimal.mark=","), parse.number(), sub(), etc.) that I googled, it still does not work.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below a possible solution

```
library(stringr)
text<-c('1231.1','4343.5','312312.0')
str_replace(string = text,pattern = "[.]",replacement = ",")

[1] "1231,1"   "4343,5"   "312312,0"
```

another possible solution is:

```
num_text<-c(1231.1,4343.5,312312.0)
gsub("\\.", ",", num_text)

[1] "1231,1" "4343,5" "312312"
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `gsub` and `format`should work

```
#format
format(bike_data_tbl$price_euro, decimal.mark = ",")

#gsub
gsub(pattern = ".", x = bike_data_tbl$price_euro, replacement = ",", fixed = TRUE)
```

However, it seems that the prices are in thousands (e.g. 1.699 for ground control model = 1699 euros. You could try this:

```
as.numeric(gsub(pattern = ".", x = bike_data_tbl$price_euro, replacement = "", fixed = TRUE))
```

The last function replaces all dots with nothing.

Comment: ```bike_data_tbl <- bike_data_tbl %>%
  rename("model" = "name")%>%
  subset(nchar(price_euro)!=0)

gsub(pattern = ".", x = bike_data_tbl$price_euro, replacement = ",", fixed = TRUE)
  
bike_data_tbl```

Comment: I did this but the tibble looks the same